# Read-from-string troubles

Tags: netlogo

I have loaded a GIS file into netlogo.  This file has a number of attributes, but I'm really only having trouble with one.  The material type is set to p, t, s, c - according to QGIS these are strings.  When I read them in they all have quotes around them and so show as "p" "t" "s" "c" and no turtles are returned from:

```
ask turtles with [is-string? material-type = false] [show who]
```

The problem I have is when I try to read-from-string.  Netlogo raises the error: expected constant.

Any thoughts?  I have looked around for an answer, but most are a little different.

Comment: Why are you calling `read-from-string` on these strings? What result do you expect, if the input string is something like "p"?

Comment: Just as you wrote your answer - I thought "why would I want to read it as a string - as no number exists in the quotes" - and so nothing can be done.